# Sum all lines of a csv file

Tags: csv, awk

I have got a .csv files, with some numbers, I want to get a new file with the same number of rows and one column, with the sum of the numbers of the corresponding row in the original .csv file.

**Input example** (note the whitespaces, I hope this would not be a problem)

```
 2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
 3,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
 4,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
 5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
 6,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
```

**Expected output**

```
2
4
5
6
7
```

**My code** (not producing any output):

```
    file_out="output.txt"
    file_in="input.txt"
    cmd3="sum_file=\$(awk -F, '
    {
        sum = 0; 
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            sum += \$i;
        }
        print sum;
    }
    ' ${file_in})"
    echo $cmd3
    eval $cmd3
    eval "echo ${sum_file} > ${file_out}"
```

You can propose also tools different from awk, but I would be glad to know why my code does not work, maybe because of the whitespaces (I do not think so).

Comment: Why are you storing your code in a variable and then `eval`ing it?  That seems very convoluted. Are there any requirements you're not telling us?

Comment: Wait, what output are you expecting? To the screen? You are redirecting to the output file. Is that file empty?

Comment: @glennjackman, the problem was in the last line. I should have used `\${sum_file}`. I was using eval for debug purposes, since it was easy to echo the lines. But doing so I introduced a new bug :( At least now is solved

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any temporary values. Just execute `awk` and redirect output to file.

```
file_out="output.txt"
file_in="input.txt"
awk -F, '
{
    sum = 0; 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum += \$i;
    }
    print sum;
}
' "${file_in}" > "${file_out}"
```

Comment: You don't really need to have the file names in variables, either. If you do, they should be inside double quotes. (It seems to work fine as long as your file names are trivial, but when it breaks, we get another one in the landfill of desperate newbie questions about why this doesn't work on file names with asterisks, spaces, square brackets etc in their names.)

Comment: Good point, @tripleee

Comment: `sum += \$i;` causes a syntax error unless it's part of e.g. `cmd3="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

`awk`:

```
awk -F, '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sum+= $i} print sum}' input.txt > output.txt
```

`perl`:

```
perl -F, -lane '$s=0; $s+=$_ for @F; print $s' input.txt > output.txt
```